# Is it possible to pause a task?

Tags: task, plc

I'm using Sysmac Studio v1.30 by Omron and wondered if there was any function to pause a task from the primary task?

I want to be able to pause a task after a security boolean variable turns true then continue with its operation after the boolean turn false.